# Lightning-Map Runs Outside Container On Mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

I've been trying to figure out how to get a lightning-map to not overflow on mobile, but everything I seem to try to get it to stay contained will not work. Has anyone had to work with this before and been able to change the display size?

This is how it looks currently:

[image]

```
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-p-around_medium">
            <header class="slds-page-header__title slds-align_absolute-center">Service Appointments</header>
            <template if:false={mapMarkersLoaded}>
                <lightning-spinner 
                size="medium"
                variant="brand" >
            </lightning-spinner>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <lightning-card class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-body-regular">
                Please wait while the map loads...
            </lightning-card>
            </template>

            <template if:true={mapMarkersLoaded}>
                <div class="slds-box slds-size_4-of-6 slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning-map class="slds-size_5-of-6 slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-around_x-small" 
                    flexibility="auto"
                    map-markers={mapMarkersPlusCurrent}
                    list-view="hidden"
                    zoom-level="10"
                    center={currentLocation}
                    options={mapOptions}
                    >
                    </lightning-map>
                </div>
                <div if:true={mapMarkersExist} class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-body-regular"> Today you have {numAppts} service appointments scheduled</div>
                <template if:true={mapMarkersExist}>
                    <template for:each={mapMarkers} for:item="appt">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-box" onclick={handleNavigate} data-item={appt.saId} key={appt.saId} ><b>{appt.description}</b><br>{appt.title}<br> {appt.location.Street}, {appt.location.City}, {appt.location.State} {appt.location.PostalCode} 
                            <br><lightning-button class="slds-float--right" label="Arrived on Site" data-item={appt.saId} onclick={launchFlow}></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    

</template>
```

Comment: what does the component markup look like?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/359756/edit) your question to add your code. (The SE editor has lots of formatting options - be sure to put triple tickmarks (```) above and below your sections of code so that they format properly for easier reading.)

Comment: @glls just added it beneath the image

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to find a solution to resizing this component, it does appear to not overflow on the mobile app. For whatever reason it looks completely different when using chrome dev tools, but in the App it sizes correctly.